# Using loquacious class mappings in NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am trying to use the new loquacious class mapping feature that we used to get out of Fluent NHibernate. But I am getting stuck on how to get the class mappings to the configuration. I have read F Maulo's blog ( http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2011/04/me-on-fluent-nhibernate.html ) on it but I can't seem to get it to work. Do any of you have any information on how to add this to the NH configuration?

Regards,

Found the answer based on the reaction

```
  foreach (string mappingAssembly in MappingsAssembly.Split(','))
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(mappingAssembly)) continue;
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(mappingAssembly);
            types.AddRange(assembly.GetTypes());
            //  configuration.AddAssembly(assembly);
        }
        configuration.DataBaseIntegration(x => GetDatabaseConfig(x));

        ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();

        mapper.AddMappings(types);
        var compiledMapping = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitAddedEntities();

        configuration.AddMapping(compiledMapping);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something along these lines:

```
ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
// your mappings by code
Type[] types = new Type[] {}; // your mapped types here
// compile mappings
HbmMapping mapping = mapper.CompileMappingFor(types);
// create configuration
Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
// add mappings to config
cfg.AddDeserializedMapping(hbm,"documentname");
```

Just remember that doing the mappings by code gives you quite a few new possibilities: eg: you can get the list of mapped types with Assembly.GetTypes().

Answer (score 1):

If you are already doing Fluent, the easiest would be to keep you separate mapping files and load them all in at startup.  So I have an initialization class that defines a class level variable

```
    private ModelMapper _mapper = new ModelMapper();
```

then I call Initialize()

```
    public void Initialize()
    {
        Configure = new Configuration();
        Configure.SessionFactoryName(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SessionFactoryName"]);
        Configure.DataBaseIntegration(db =>
                                      {
                                        db.Dialect<MsSql2008Dialect>();
                                        db.Driver<SqlClientDriver>();
                                        db.KeywordsAutoImport = Hbm2DDLKeyWords.AutoQuote;
                                        db.IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted;
                                        db.ConnectionStringName = ConnectionStringName;
                                        db.BatchSize = 20;
                                        db.Timeout = 10;
                                        db.HqlToSqlSubstitutions = "true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N'";
                                      });
        Configure.SessionFactory().GenerateStatistics();

        Map();
    }
```

then my Map() method is this

```
    private void Map()
    {
        _mapper.AddMappings(MappingAssembly.GetExportedTypes());
        Configure.AddDeserializedMapping(_mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities(), "MyWholeDomain"); 
    }
```

I like to pass my mapping assembly name in through my appSettings.